# Eclipse plugin development - JavaDoc like hover hint for JavaScript (Eclipse JSDT)

Tags: javascript, eclipse, hover, eclipse-plugin, jsdt

How to implement hover hint for JavaScript (Eclipse JSDT).

I want when user hover over some keyword, some description is shown, like description in code completions:

[image]
<sub>(source: [nodeclipse.org](http://www.nodeclipse.org/img/Completion-for-base-Node.js-modules.PNG))</sub>

But that description should be also way to move that window into View stack in the bottom on Windows (Just like JavaDoc)

Answer (score 0):

Did you open an enhancement request for JSDT on Eclipse Bugzilla?